# What type of object should this function return?

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, smart-pointers, lifetime

Consider this class:

```
class Widget
{
    Widget::Widget();
    bool initialize();
}
```

A `Widget` has the following characteristics:

1. `initialize()` must be invoked to fully construct
2. `initialize()` may fail
3. `initialize()` is expensive

Given that, I am encapsulating creation in factory function that always returns the same `Widget` instance:

```
Widget* widget() {
    static auto w = new Widget;
    static auto initialized = false;

    if (!initialized) {
        if (!w->initialize()) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        initialized = true;
    }

    return w;
}
```

**What should the return type of `widget()` be?**

In particular, I'd like to somehow make it clear that the lifetime of the returned `Widget` will outlast any caller, but without referencing the internal implementation.

1. Return a raw pointer and add a comment that states "The returned pointer points to an object with static storage duration that will not be deleted before the end of the program". This is simple, but not self-documenting.
2. Return a `std::shared_ptr<Widget>`. This is self-documenting, but I don't like that it will introduce completely unnecessary reference counting overhead.
3. Return a `std::unique_ptr<Widget>` with a custom deleter function that is a no-op. I think this has the same perceived problem as #2 if the caller converts it into a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: It's really a matter of opinion, but in this particular case I wouldn't worry about refcounting overhead. If your Widget type "is expensive" to create, than any "unnecessary reference counting overhead" is likely to be trivial by comparison.

Comment: The C++ language doesn't encourage using interfaces enough.  But yes, they are a complete pita to debug, exposing implementation is hard to pass up.

Comment: Should we be ignoring the multithread-unsafeness of this?  (Even in C++11 this isn't safe)

Comment: I don't think Factory is the correct term for this. In my mind a factory is something that creates an object and passes ownership to the caller. This is more like a Singleton.

Comment: I don't think 2. and 3. are self documenting at all. If I call a function that returns a `std::shared_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` I expect to be taking shared/unique ownership.

Comment: @AndreKostur Thread safety is not an issue for my purposes, but feel free to comment on that.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I'm not really sure what else to call it. IMHO, singleton implies that there can only be one instance at a time and that's not the case here. I removed "factory" from the title.

Comment: @JoshuaJohnson Assuming C++11: While the initialization of the static variables is guaranteed to be threadsafe (it's the runtime's responsibility to ensure that the static initialization only happens once), the code that's checking `if (!initialized)` is unsafe.  If the `widget()` function is called in two threads nearly simultaneously, it is possible for both threads to think that `initialized` is still false, and they both will call `initialize()`.  Particularly if `initialize()` make take some time, this would increase the possibility of double-initialization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I vote for:

```
boost::optional<Widget&> widget() {
    static Widget w; // no reason for this to be a pointer
    static bool initialized = false;

    if (!initialized) {
        if (!w.initialize()) {
            return boost::none;
        }
        initialized = true;
    }

    return w;
}
```

It makes it clear that the caller doesn't own the `Widget` in any way, there's no worry of the caller `delete`-ing the `Widget`, and it's clear whether or not the call succeeded.

Comment: What about in an environment w/o Boost?

Comment: @JoshuaJohnson You could just copy `optional` from there - it's a header only library. There's also [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). Or you could just write your own class that has a possibly-null `Widget*` member that you have to dereference to get out.

Comment: experimental optional has no reference support, last I checked.

Comment: @JoshuaJohnson  If `shared_ptr` is considered unnecessary overhead, doesn't optional introduce overhead ? Is that ok for you ?

Comment: @Yakk http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/optional_references.html

Comment: @Drax I said experimental optional, as in `std::experimental::optional` as opposed to `boost::optional`.

Comment: @Yakk my bad, I'll leave the link there for curious people though :)

Answer (score 7):

Isn't a raw pointer the right thing to do here?  It expresses the restrictions already.  It can fail (by returning nullptr), and since it makes no promises about the pointer, callers can't safely cause it to be deleted.  You're getting a raw pointer, you can't make the assumption that you're allowed to make any statements about the lifetime of the pointed-to object.

Comment: I think a raw pointer is fine. It documents the fact that the caller is not expected to take ownership and it could be null. I think whatever option is chosen it still needs to be made clear with comments or naming conventions that this is a Singleton so the lifetime is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Herb Sutter's recommendation in this case (item 4 at http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/) is to return `optional`.

> There could be one additional reason the function might have returned a pointer, namely to return nullptr to indicate failure to produce an object. Normally it’s better throw an exception to report an error if we fail to load the widget. However, if not being able to load the widget is normal operation and should not be considered an error, return an optional, and probably make the factory noexcept if no other kinds of errors need to be reported than are communicated well by returning an empty optional.

Comment: Isn't Herb talking about the case where the caller takes ownership of the object being returned?

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. I wonder if it's best to delete this answer then?

Answer (score 1):

As other people noted if the factory will only produce one item, factory perhaps is not the right term. It seems a Singleton.

Taking in account that:

- We will create only one instance of Widget
- That instance will be constructed the first time someone ask for it (if any)
- That instance will live until program end AND should be destroyed then
- Nobody should delete the instance

I'll try something like this:

```
class Widget {
public:
    static Widget& Instance() {
        static Widget w{};
        return w;
    }

private:
    Widget() {
        // Expensive construction
    }
    Widget(const Widget&) = delete; // avoid copy

};
```

Comment: This is fine but it doesn't handle the situation where initialization might fail.

Answer (score 0):

To make lifetime and ownership clearer I would use the conventions of the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and make your function a static `getInstance` function on the `Widget` class.

```
class Widget {
  bool initialize();
 public:
  static Widget* getInstance() {
    static Widget w;
    static bool initialized = false;

    if (!initialized) {
      if (!w.initialize()) {
         return nullptr;
      }
      initialized = true;
    }
    return &w;
  }
};
```

I think a raw pointer return type documents the fact that the caller is not expected to take ownership and it could be null.